# Stylus CSS compilation and Maven

Tags: maven, stylus

Is there any convenient way, how to recursively compile all [Stylus stylesheets](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) inside standard java web-applications built with Maven?

I found there is a [lesscss-maven-plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.lesscss/lesscss-maven-plugin), but is there anything similar for Stylus?

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a project with Maven, Java, Spring and Stylus.

Backend side of the project use Spring. And Java Developers setup that side of the project and gave me a command to start Java server. I implemented that command to npm by correcting config paths. Then i proxy the port of java and serve frontend app through my port to backend port.
Lastly: I made stylus and js output to **resources/static** folder of spring.

**Shortly;** I don't use maven for stylus. I don't think any tool exist for maven. I use node and npm for that. Tools for Stylus built using node not maven. There is a javascript compilation process.

I think you have to setup node and npm. Welcome to the frontend hell of web.